# Access images after tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using  tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory to load my images into a dataset for tensorflow. However, I'm confused about how it works. I simply want to be able to imshow each image from the dataset.

```
data = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Skyrmion Vision/testFiles/train/',batch_size=1,image_size=(171,256))
data_iterator = data.as_numpy_iterator()
batch = data_iterator.next()
batch[0].shape
for image in batch:
  print(type(image))
```

This was my attempt, but it simply shows 2 numpy.ndarrays as the type, I expected it to show all 12 images as numpy arrays (There are only 12 images in the dataset).

How can I access the images after they are in the tensorflow dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created batches of one element each by setting `batch_size=1`.

So if you do:

```
data_iterator = data.as_numpy_iterator()
batch = data_iterator.next()
```

You are only accessing one image because your batch only has one image in it. To get the next batch, and so, the next image, you can call again `data_iterator.next()`.

However if you only want to iterate through your dataset and print the images, you can do like this:

```
data = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory('img',batch_size=1,image_size=(171,256))
for x, y in data:
  print("image: {}, label: {}".format(x,y))
```

Of course you can also set a higher value of `batch_size` to access more images at a time.

If you want to access an image at a time, you can either:

---

**Method 1** (advised): iterate through your batches, and through the images within a batch:

```
import numpy as np
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

data = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory('img',batch_size=1,image_size=(171,256))
for batch_x, batch_y in data:
    for i, x in enumerate(batch_x):
       x = np.asarray(x)
       cv2_imshow(x)
```

The inner loop lets you access separately the images inside the batch. With `for batch_x, batch_y in data` you obtain two arrays where the first dimension is the number of samples inside the batch. So if you add an inner loop, you can iterate through the elements of your batch. In this case there is only one element, but the loop makes the approach more general.

---

**Method 2:** access the images within a batch using an index.

Having set `batch_size=1`, each batch has only one image. So each `batch_x` element of the loop is an array of shape `(1, 171, 256, 3)`. Let's say you set `batch_size=2`. This would give you a `batch_x` shape of `(2, 171, 256, 3)`. At this point if you want to display the second (i.e. index 1) image of each batch, you can do this by indexing the image directly:

```
import numpy as np
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

data = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory('img', batch_size=2, image_size=(171,256))
for batch_x, batch_y in data:
    x = np.asarray(batch_x[1])  # access second image of batch
    cv2_imshow(x)
```

---

The method `cv2_imshow` is used to display the images in Google Colab.

Comment: ok i tried the for loop, and it works, but i can't view the image. I did:
`for x, y in data:
  plt.imshow(x)` and I got TypeError: Invalid shape (1, 171, 256, 3) for image data

Comment: I've updated the answer, have a look

Comment: Thats perfect! Thank you :) 

I did have to change asarray to np.asarray(x) but otherwise excellent.

Comment: Just so I understand, can you show me how the access with batch_x[0] would look?

Comment: Sure, I've added an example

Comment: when i try method 2 I get this error: InvalidArgumentError: slice index 1 of dimension 0 out of bounds. [Op:StridedSlice] name: strided_slice/

Comment: I forgot to update inside the example `batch_size=2`. Of course you want to access the second element of the batch (index 1), so the `batch_size` must at least be 2.

Comment: ok that worked, i have to display two images per loop (batch_x[0] and batch_x[1]) to get every image, but, thank you!

Comment: Yes, or you could switch back to have `batch_size=1` and do `batch_x[0]`.  There are lots of ways to achieve the same result actually